# "vue running in developer mode" warning appears even when running in production mode

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli-3

I am running vue in production mode but i still get the warning of vue running in developer mode
[image]

the project is running fine and i can see that it running in production mode. but i am still getting the warning "You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production."

Below are my vue.config.js main.js and dockerfile
vue.config.js file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3123,
        disableHostCheck: true,
    },
    publicPath: './',
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                // allow access to process.env from within the vue app
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
                }
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                '$': 'jquery',
            }),
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        ]
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            config.plugin('define')
            .tap(definitions => {
                    definitions[0] = Object.assign(definitions[0], {
                        'process.env': {
                            NODE_ENV: "'production-with-warns'"
                        }
                    });
                    return definitions
                });
        }

        config.module
            .rule('vue')
            .use('vue-loader')
            .tap(args => {
                args.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve'
            })
    },
    lintOnSave: false,
    transpileDependencies: ['vue2-datatable-component']
};
```

main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap3-dialog';
import 'bootstrap3-dialog/dist/css/bootstrap-dialog.css'
import 'bootstrap-select';
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css'
import 'cropperjs'
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css'
import 'flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css'
import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker'
import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css'
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
import './useCompositionApi'

import App from './atar/App.vue';
import store from './store.js';
import routerConfig from './router.js';
import filters from './filters.js';
import resource from './resource.js';
import directives from './directives';
import mixins from './mixins';
import i18n from './i18n';

import * as uiv from 'uiv';
import Datatable from 'vue2-datatable-component';
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto';
import VueNotification from 'vue-notification';
import AsyncComputed from 'vue-async-computed';

import extensions from './extensions';
import windowConfiguration from './windowConfiguration.js';
import VueAutosize from 'vue-autosize';
import errorHandler from "./errorHandler.js";
import EventBusPlugin from "./plugin/EventBusPlugin";
import WindowResizePlugin from "./plugin/WindowResizePlugin";
import ScrollPlugin from "./plugin/ScrollPlugin";

import 'nodelist-foreach';
import WSSubscriber from "./plugin/WSSubscriber";
import validationConfiguration from "./veeValidateConfiguration";

import { AppInitializer } from "./AppInitializer";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push;
VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location) {
    return originalPush.call(this, location).catch(error => {
        if (error.name !== "NavigationDuplicated") {
            throw error;
        }
    });
}
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(uiv);
Vue.use(VueAutosize);
Vue.use(Datatable);
Vue.use(VueScrollTo, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: "ease",
    offset: 0,
    cancelable: true,
    onDone: false,
    onCancel: false,
    x: false,
    y: true
});
Vue.use(VueNotification);
Vue.use(AsyncComputed);
Vue.use(EventBusPlugin);
Vue.use(WindowResizePlugin);
Vue.use(ScrollPlugin);
Vue.use(WSSubscriber);

new AppInitializer()
    .addStep(() => resource.configure())
    .addStep((ctx) => store.configure(ctx))
    .addStep(() => filters.configure())
    .addStep(() => mixins.configure())
    .addStep(() => directives.configure())
    .addStep(() => i18n.configure())
    .addStep(() => windowConfiguration.configure())
    .addStep(() => validationConfiguration.configure())
    .addStep(() => {
        Vue.config.productionTip = false;
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
            Vue.config.devtools = false;
        }
    })
    .addStep((ctx) => {
        ctx['router'] = new VueRouter(routerConfig);
    })
    .addStep((ctx) => {
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            router: ctx['router'],
            store: new Vuex.Store(ctx['store']),
            render: h => h(App)
        });
    })
    .addStep((ctx) => {
        ctx['router'].afterEach((route) => {
            document.title = route.meta.titleProducer(route);
        });
    })
    .addStep(() => extensions.configureGlobal())
    .addStep(() => errorHandler.configure())
    .initialize();
```

docker file

```
# a.k.a. node:lts-alpine
FROM node:14.17.4-alpine as app-build-stage

RUN apk add git
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm i -g @vue/cli-service@4.5.15 @vue/cli-plugin-babel@4.5.15 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@4.5.15 @vue/cli-plugin-typescript@4.5.15 @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest@4.5.15 vue-template-compiler@2.6.14 typescript@4.6.3 autoprefixer@8.6.5 less-loader@4.1.0 less@3.9.0 webpack@4.46.0 babel-loader@8.2.3 @babel/core@7.16.0

COPY ./package*.json ./legal_notice.sh ./

RUN npm ci --production
RUN npm link @vue/cli-service @vue/cli-plugin-babel @vue/cli-plugin-eslint @vue/cli-plugin-typescript @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest vue-template-compiler typescript autoprefixer less-loader less webpack babel-loader @babel/core

COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN export freeMem=$(free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print $4}') &&\
    export minRequiredMem=2048 &&\
    if [[ $freeMem -lt $minRequiredMem ]];\
        then\
        echo "[WARNING] Free memory ($freeMem MB) is less than the required limit ($minRequiredMem MB)." &&\
        echo "[WARNING] Build is likely to fail due to insufficient memory.";\
    fi;\
    npm run build;\
    if [[ ! -d "/app/dist" ]];\
        then echo "The npm build process has failed and /app/dist folder is not found.";\
        if [[ $freeMem -lt $minRequiredMem ]];\
            then\
            echo "Free memory : $freeMem MB";\
            echo "Minimum memory required : $minRequiredMem MB";\
            echo "The build has failed most likely due to insufficient memory.";\
            exit 1;\
        fi\
    fi



WORKDIR /app
COPY ./docker/package*.json ./docker/server.js ./docker/apiinfo.js.template ./docker/entrypoint.sh /app/
RUN apk upgrade
RUN npm ci

# there are some overlay issues in the Jenkins so rm -rf ..../npm/ is not applicable
RUN find /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/ -type f -exec rm -f {} \;

COPY --from=app-build-stage /app/dist /app/static/

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `build` command under `package.json` file, the `development` mode is set in the `build` command. like so...

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "devserve": "run-s build:dev watch",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
}
```

I usually have two build commands configured, one to build for production and one for development

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "devserve": "run-s build:dev watch",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "build:dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "build:prod": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
}
```

Make sure to run `npm run build:prod` for a production build and then deploy and the error should not appear.

Comment: I have no mode specified in my package.json i just have vue-cli-service build.  Wouldnt this by default run production?.. also i have tried with adding the mode but the warning still appears

Comment: yes, if there is no mode then default is production. when you run npm run build it should be indicating that it is building for production. basic stuff...but did you deploy after running npm run build ..

Comment: i.e what i mean is you are seeing the warning on your deployed site...wherever that is...and it is not when you run ....npm run serve locally...because locally it is going to default to development mode..

Comment: Yes i deployed it after running npm run build. I have jenkins pipeline for this and deployed in linux machine Even after setting the mode i am getting the same warning

Comment: @prateeknaik that is pretty strange, as far as i am aware there are only 2 possiblities...one is the build command, which you confirmed is defined correctly...second is that your jenkins pipeline is picking up the correct dist/build folder from the correct environment..... maybe you can thoroughly check on the latter.

Comment: I did check it.. we push our code to github repo and jenkins job picks it directly from there and deploys it and as far as in jenkins build steps runs npm run build and pushes it to artifactory to be used. We have kubernetes cluster where i have services defined to deploy it. There also i have added env - NODE_ENV  to production

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251816/discussion-between-thezohaan-and-prateeknaik).